Working of differential pair using MOSFETs
I am currently learning about differential pair using MOSFET from this course. In this particular lecture, the teacher says that to have a differential pair we need to apply the second signal v2 at the source through a buffer as shown below because impedance at source of the MOSFET is \$1/g_m\$.

To implement a buffer he uses a source follower like this:

The source voltage of this source follower will be almost equal to v2 if the \$g_mR_l >> 1\$, where \$R_l\$ is the load connected at the source terminal of source follower because:
Output voltage of source follower: $$\frac{g_mR_l \times v_2}{1+g_mR_l}$$
But later he connects the voltage buffer to the initial amplifier as shown below:

Now the doubt that I have is that now the impedance at the output of source follower is \$1/g_m\$ which is much much less than 1 and therefore according to the formula above the output of voltage buffer is no longer equal to the input voltage v2 and therefore it is not a good differential pair anymore.
Is my logic correct or am I making a mistake?

Your differential pair isn't biased properly, for one thing.

I know that. The professor in the linked lecture is only talking about the small signal model. In the later lectures he tells how to bias.

Yes, the voltage at the middle node (source) is vs = (v1+v2)/2 which can be obtained by superposition. Assume v2 = 0, vs= 1/gm1/(1/gm1+1/gm2)v1 = 1/2v1. Similarly you get 1/2*v2 so the total voltage is vs = (v1+v2)/2.
